# Touch Hover Functionality in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm working on a website where I have enabled aria-haspopup so it can work on Surface pro. The reason I'm doing that is because the first touch needs to show the css animation and the second touch needs to activate the actual url.

It works great in Edge & IE but I need it to work in Chrome. Are there any javascript alternatives to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would try using focus and hover properties together to trigger the animations.

Comment: Something like this: a.classname:hover, a.classname:focus;?